# How to fix "compile error: next without for" error in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

So I am very new to coding to VBA or to programming in general. I am receiving a "Compile error: Next without for". I believe I am giving 3 nexts for 3 fors but still I have no clue. Below is the code I am working on....

Sub width2() 'to assign series width automatically

```
For Series = 1 To 24  'chart series, 144 combinations
        For i = 0 To 1
                For j = 0 To 11
                    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(Series).Select
                    With Selection.Format.Line
                        .Visible = msoTrue
                        .Weight = Sheet5.Range("Q9").Offset((9 * i) + 6, (3 * j)).Value
                Next j
        Next i
Next Series
End Sub
```

Not sure where the mistake is. 
Any help much appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: you are missing `End With` to your `With Selection.Format.Line`

Comment: May be problem in `With` method. You do not close `With`. You have to use `End With` before `Next j`.

Comment: After adding end with before next j , I am now getting : "The item with the specified name was not found" for line:     ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate

Comment: Make shure there is a chart named `Chart 4` in your active sheet...

Comment: @PiyushVerma please update your code with the `End With` , so we will remove that error from you post. Secod, you need to take your `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate` and the following line from inside the nested `For` loops to be the first line in your `Sub`. Just keep the `.Weight = Sheet5.Range("Q9").Offset((9 * i) + 6, (3 * j)).Value` inside

Comment: Hi Shai. I got rid of all the previous errors, but somehow offsetting is going wrong by taking wrong values. So I have to look linbe by line to understand the process. But when I try to debug the code line by line I am getting `Compile error: Expected: # `. Though the code as a whole runs through a button which has this macro assigned.

Comment: Complete code:
`
Sub Width()
     For i = 0 To 1
        
                For j = 0 To 11
                    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12 * i + j + 1).Select
                    With Selection.Format.Line
                        .Visible = msoTrue
                        .Weight = Sheet5.Range("Q9").Offset((9 * i), (3 * j)).Value
                    End With
                
                Next j
  Next i

End Sub
`

Comment: you want to `Offset` 9 rows for each `Series` ? and 3 columns per `Series` ?

Comment: Yes, my values lie in excel in that fashion. So when i reaches 1 somehow j starts with 1 also instead starting from 0, that's making the offset to shift from 2nd row onwards.

Comment: @PiyushVerma can you share your workbook structure data ? where you want to pull your `Weight` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share your Worksheet Data structure, this is not the full answer.

The code runs without the need to use `Activate`, `ActiveChart` and `Select`. Instead it references the "Chart 6" `ChartObject` and then modifies the `Line.Visible` and `Line.Weight` properites of the `SeriesCollection` using the following `With` statement: `With MyCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(12 * i + j + 1)`.

**Note**: if @Piyush Verma decides to share his data structue, also the math part of `Sheet5.Range("Q9").Offset((9 * i) + 6, (3 * j)).Value` can be handled.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartSer_LineWidth()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim MyCht As ChartObject

' set the chart object of Chart 6 to a variable
Set MyCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6")

For i = 0 To 1
    For j = 0 To 11

        With MyCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(12 * i + j + 1)
            .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
            .Format.Line.Weight = Sheet5.Range("Q9").Offset((9 * i), (3 * j)).Value
        End With

    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: you're welcome, please mark as answer (click the little **V** next to my answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
For Series = 1 To 24  'chart series, 144 combinations
    For i = 0 To 1
            For j = 0 To 11
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(Series).Select
                With Selection.Format.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .Weight = Sheet5.Range("Q9").Offset((9 * i) + 6, (3 * j)).Value
                End With
            Next j
    Next i
 Next Series
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close every "With" with "EndWith". That is ommitted in your code.

Also close every "if" with "EndIf" and "for" with "Next", to avoid "Compile error: Next without for"